# How to get values from a macOS built in Application Color Meter?

Tags: macos, applescript, color-picker

I am building a mini project where I want to have a color picker feature. I found the Digital Color Meter on macOS is helpful. I did some search and found I can write a simple AppleScript to activate the application.

[image]

It would be awesome if I can monitor the next left-click mouse event (even if I am not focusing Digital Color Meter application). By monitoring the next left-click mouse event, I want to get the value from the R, G and B options as you can see from the image above.

I think mouse event handler should be able to achieve (though I don't know how to do it). I am not sure whether I can read the value from the Application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
choose color
```

from Standard Scripting Additions.

In the color picker window there is also a eyedropper (pipette).

Comment: Thanks for point it out! I've found some useful AppleScript to do this... But I'd prefer to use Digital Color Meter for this.

Comment: Digital Color Meter is not scriptable and vanilla AppleScript can't monitor mouse events.

Comment: Oh sure, that makes sense. Thanks!